# How to make my VBA code look better and reduce redundancy?

Tags: vba

I have written very ugly VBA code, but I don't know how I can make this look better.
I have a function (say `Function Main`) that calls another 3 functions inside it. These 3 functions have to happen in order, and if one fails, the rest shouldn't happen. Also, I need to retrieve proper, descriptive error message. I have another software that invokes VBA code and calls this `Main` function, and if there is an error, I need to use that information, so I am returning a value (either a descriptive error message or "Completed") from `Main` as well.

```
Function Main
    Dim result As String
    result = ProcessA();
    If result <> "OK" Then
        Main = result
        Exit Function
    End If
    result = ProcessB();
    If result <> "OK" Then
        Main = result
        Exit Function
    End If
    result = ProcessC();
    If result <> "OK" Then
        Main = result
        Exit Function
    End If
    Main = "Completed"
End Function

Function ProcessA()
    On Error GoTo Errored


        'Do some operation


        ProcessA = "OK" 'At the end of operation, assign OK and
        Exit Function 'Exit function here

    Errored: 'In case of an error, get error information and return it
        ProcessA = "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) _
                   & "Error Description: " & Err.Description & Chr(13) _
                   & "Error at Process A"
End Function

'ProcessB and ProcessC also have a very similar style.
```

As you can see, my `Main` function has so many redundant code, but I can't think of any other better way. Could someone give me advice on how to make this better?

Comment: I `think` you can assign the function result directly to `Main` and stop using `result` and save a few lines. You could also move a single error handler into Main and capture all errors there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest re-throwing the error then catching it in the calling method:

```vb
Function Main()
    
    On Error GoTo haveError
    ProcessA
    ProcessB
    ProcessC
    Main = "Completed"
    Exit Function
    
haveError:
   Main = err.Description
End Function

Sub ProcessA()
    On Error GoTo Errored
    'Do some operation
    Exit Sub
Errored:     
    err.Raise Number:=err.Number, Description:=DescribeError(err, "ProcessA")
End Sub

Sub ProcessB()
    On Error GoTo Errored
    'Do some operation
    Debug.Print 1 / 0   'eg. error here....
    Exit Sub
Errored:     
    err.Raise Number:=err.Number, Description:=DescribeError(err, "ProcessB")
End Sub

Sub ProcessC()
    On Error GoTo Errored
    'Do some operation
    Exit Sub
Errored:     
    err.Raise Number:=err.Number, Description:=DescribeError(err, "ProcessC")
End Sub

'utility
Function DescribeError(err As ErrObject, procName As String)
    DescribeError = "Error in method: " & procName & vbLf & _
                    "Error Line: " & erl & vbLf & _
                    "Error Description: " & err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Thats how to do it!

Comment: Thank you everyone! I didn't know you could "rethrow" in VBA! I learned so much from everyone's answers here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Function Main
    Dim result As String
    result = ProcessA(): If result <> "OK" Then goto errResult
    result = ProcessB(): If result <> "OK" Then goto errResult 
    result = ProcessC(): If result <> "OK" Then goto errResult 

    Main = "Completed"
    Exit Function 
errResult:
    Main=result 
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Application.Run()`, you can process any number of steps in a loop:

```
Function Main()
    Dim f, result
    For Each f In Array("ProcessA", "ProcessB", "ProcessC") ' and so on
        result = Application.Run(f)
        If result <> "OK" Then
            Main = result
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Main = "Completed"
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Private errorMsg As String

Function Main()
    If ProcessA Then
        If ProcessB Then
            If ProcessC Then
                Main = "Completed"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    If Main = vbNullString Then Main = errorMsg
End Function

Private Function ProcessA() As Boolean
    ProcessA = True
Exit Function
Err:
    
    ReportError "Process A"
End Function

Private Sub ReportError(argSrc As String)
    errorMsg = "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) _
                   & "Error Description: " & Err.Description & Chr(13) _
                   & "Error at " & argSrc
End Sub
```